# Bootstrap 4 Align Items within a Row or Column Seperately

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4 to create a row of 2 items within a column where the first item stays all the way to the left in the row and the second item is always centered in the row. I am able to do this with my own CSS. Is there a way to do this only using Bootstrap with no extra CSS?

Here is my CSS:

```
.float_left {
    float:left;
}

.float_center {
        float: right;
        position: relative;
        left: -50%;
        text-align: left;
}

.float_center > .child {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
}
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="row" >
    <div class="col-12" style="z-index:5000;">       

        <span class="float_left">Left</span>

        <div class="float_center">
            <span class="child">Center</span>                        
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. `display:flex;` will make the data to sit in single row.
> 2. When you assign `width` of equal size ie `50%` and move the text to left, that will sit in the center without extra code.
> 3. Flex is good for layout design, so don't worry about responsiveness it will take care of that as well.

```css
.align {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
}

.float_left,
.float_center {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 align" style="z-index:5000;">

    <span class="float_left">Left</span>

    <div class="float_center">
      <span class="child">Center</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use col? I think this will work.

```
<div class="row" >
        <div class="col-12" style="z-index:5000;">       

            <div class="row">
                <span class="col">Left</span>

                <div class="col">
                    <span class="child">Center</span>                        
                </div>
            </div>
        </div.
    </div>
```

if you want fixed width for left side custom width